# Do Ubuntu PHP repositories expire?

Tags: php, docker, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

Disclaimer: I'm not very intimately familiar with linux, ubuntu, docker etc. I know only some stuff...

---

Software context: Ubuntu 16.04 + docker + docker-compose

I have a Dockerfile which, among other things, also installs PHP 7.2:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
....
RUN LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --force-yes php7.2-bcmath php7.2-cli php7.2-common php7.2-curl \
                php7.2-cgi php7.2-dev php7.2-fpm php7.2-gd php7.2-gmp php7.2-imap php7.2-intl \
                php7.2-json php7.2-mbstring php7.2-mysql \
                php7.2-opcache php7.2-phpdbg php7.2-mongodb \
                php7.2-readline php7.2-recode \
                php7.2-tidy php7.2-xml php7.2-xsl php7.2-zip \
                && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
....
```

Last time I built that image was **just a few weeks ago** and **it worked just fine**, the containers which I started from that image behave as expected.

I recently discovered I also need PHP's SOAP extension (don't ask why...), so I simply added the extension `php7.2-soap` in the list above and did this:

```
docker-compose stop
docker-compose build <my_docker_service_name>
```

The build started and, after downloading a few things, it stops:

```
....
Get:112 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 shtool all 2.0.8-8 [122 kB]
W: --force-yes is deprecated, use one of the options starting with --allow instead.
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/tzdata/tzdata_2018g-0ubuntu0.16.04_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_4.4.0-140.166_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl-dev_1.1.1-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php-defaults/php-common_68+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_all.deb  404  Not Found

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
Fetched 57.5 MB in 43s (1331 kB/s)
ERROR: Service '<my_service_name>' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y --force-yes php7.2 (....) && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

So I said to myself that simply adding the SOAP extension doesn't work. If you go to the ppa:ondrej/php PPA page, you'll see that it's super confusing because other extensions that Docker successfully installs are not listed there. That's why I thought adding SOAP to the list might work.

So I removed the `php7.2-soap` extension from the list and, out of curiosity, I tried building the image again. And... surprise: **it failed** in the exact same way. Even though **it used to work perfectly just a few weeks ago**.

---

So my questions are:

1). Any idea how to add the SOAP extension there? I was thinking of using the official PHP image from DockerHub but it can be quite difficult to make it work together with the other stuff I already have in my Dockerfile, most notably ngingx.

2). Because the build failed without changing anything in the Dockerfile, does that mean that my way of installing PHP is flawed/outdated and should be replaced? If yes, with what? If not, why does this happen? Is it because of a simple network error? Or maybe because I'm using Ubuntu-16.04 and I should upgrade to 18.04 or similar?

Comment: Yes, this stuff does expire (not sure which specific bit). As the error suggests, try running `apt-get update` before trying to install.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Debian APT system references extremely specific versions of packages.  If there’s any sort of update to a package (bug fix, security update, spelling error in the description text, ...) it is republished with a new version number, and the package with the old version number is removed from the repository.  The usual fix to this is to re-run `apt-get update`.

It looks like your Dockerfile does this, but you’re probably tripping over one other Docker feature.  When you run `docker build` a second time, Docker says, “I’ve already run this command on this input image and know it produces this output image, so I won’t run it again”.  That can be a problem if it’s something like `apt-get update` where the upstream content does change.

The usual answer in this specific case is to always run `apt-get update` and `apt-get install` in the same RUN command.  Then if you do change the list of installed packages, Docker will first get an updated package index.

```
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y ...
```

Comment: Another alterative is to build with the --no-cache flag in docker build

Answer (score 3):

Docker will create a cache'd version of the changed filesystem at that point in time.

It is possible that the `apt-get update` command that was run earlier has outdated data compared to whatever is available now.

`docker build` will only build a repo after the lines which have been changed (in this case your `apt-get install` commands).

Try running `docker build` with the --no-cache flag like so:

```
docker-compose build --no-cache <my_docker_service_name>
```

Comment: Well, it worked. I applied both your suggestion and @DavidMaze 's. Thanks.